# Failed to execute goal in GitLab CI Pipeline

Tags: maven, gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, pipeline

When I trigger the build pipeline of my application, I get a failed to execute a goal error. However, when I build this application locally, I don't get such exception. When I build via GitLab only I get into this situation.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) on project sample-app: Execution default-clean of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5 -> org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:pom:2.0.6 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connection reset -> [Help 1]
```

For a better look, an image of the error is also attached below...
[image]

Comment: When you can, place your code, errors, etc in the post itself using the [code format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) instead of uploading images. This helps make your question more readable, and prevents issues if the images are ever deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along with my team we were investigating the root cause for this issue and we were unable to find a solution. However most frequent reason was that the GitLab-Runner running in a different server has connection issues such that this happens.

One of my team members found a solution and that worked for us. Our issue solved and now the GitLab pipeline builds and runs successfully. That worked for us and hope anyone will the similar issue would also find this helpful.

```
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <releases>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  <repositories>
```

Adding the above mentioned code block to POM file solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can go for the solution, your pipeline need to be define jdk package add:

Just make sure about the java version as per your project needs:

```
Java_Build:
  stage: build
  image: 
    name: docker:20.10
  services:
    - docker:dind
  before_script:
    - apk update
    - apk add openjdk8
    - apk add maven
  script:
    - mvn clean install
```

this will resolve the issue the RCA was about this issue is jdk not available
using apk command you can use the jdk packages in the pipeline to execute.